# Bind IsSelected Property of ListBoxItem in ListBox with Multiple selection mode

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

In WinRT App (C#) I have `List<Item> items`, which bind to `ListBox`.
`Class Item` has 2 fields: `string Name` and `bool IsSelected`. As you already understood, I want to bind `IsSelected` field to IsSelected Property of ListBoxItem.

Why I need this? Why I didn't use `SelectedItems` property of my `ListBox`?

1. When `ListBox` just loaded, I already have some Items, which must be `IsSelected = true`
2. I don't want to create another collection to store all selected items.

What I'm looking for?
I'm looking for elegant solution, like in WPF:

```
 <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
  </Style>
 </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

But we all know, that WinRT doesn't support bindings in setters at all.

I also check [nice post](http://blog.onedevjob.com/2011/10/26/workaround-for-binding-not-supported-on-stylesettervalue-in-silverlight/) in [Filip Skakun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41942/filip-skakun) blog - and this is one of solution, but I need to write some of the `BindingBuilder/BindingHelper` by my self.

And now, I know two way to solve my problem:

1. Bind `SelectedItems` property of `ListBox` and store another collection of items. - I do not like this way
2. Do it like [Filip Skakun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41942/filip-skakun) - if I find nothing I use this.

In ideal situation I want to use native solution for this, or maybe someone already wrote/tested nested `BindingBuilder` for my situation - it's will be helpful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating a derived ListBox:

```
public class MyListBox : ListBox
{
    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(
        DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);

        if (item is Item)
        {
            var binding = new Binding
            {
                Source = item,
                Path = new PropertyPath("IsSelected"),
                Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
            };

            ((ListBoxItem)element).SetBinding(ListBoxItem.IsSelectedProperty, binding);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since `Item` is the type of the ItemSource property on the `ListBox` you could remove the if statement to make the control more generic.  Actually I am not sure why that check is there in the first place.  It would make more sense in my mind to check if `element` is a `ListBoxItem`.

Comment: @Trisped Uh, no. The type of the `ItemsSource` property is `object` (or `IEnumerable` in WPF). You typically assign a collection which could still contain any type, not just an application-defined `Item` class. On the other hand, in a ListBox the element type is always `ListBoxItem` unless you also override `GetContainerForItemOverride` and return some other type. I'd recommend to start reading here: [WPF ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx).